Where is Safari search history stored for different search Profiles?
I recently created a new profile in Safari (Settings > Profiles) and I noticed that my history from that new profile is not saved in ~/Library/Safari/History.db. That makes sense because one of the reasons to use different profiles is to keep a separate history. Does anyone know where the History.db for new profiles is stored?

Found them at
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Safari/Profiles/

